# Can't build gem native extensions

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm not too sure why, but I can't seem to install any gem that involves building native extensions. Can anyone suggest how to start debugging this issue? Here's the output I get with `gem install debugger`

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
    --with-ruby-dir
    --without-ruby-dir
    --with-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
    --with-ruby-lib
    --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
/Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `block in try_compile'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:443:in `with_werror'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `try_compile'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1002:in `block in have_struct_member'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1001:in `have_struct_member'
    from extconf.rb:34:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.2.3/lib/debugger/ruby_core_source.rb:21:in `call'
    from /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.2.3/lib/debugger/ruby_core_source.rb:21:in `create_makefile_with_core'
    from extconf.rb:87:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/debugger-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/debugger-1.6.0/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

Also, I recently re-installed homebrew, so that might be the issue? And I've definitely got the XCode Developre Tools installed.

Here's the contents of mkmf.log:

```
○ cat /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/debugger-1.6.0/ext/ruby_debug/mkmf.log
"/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 -o conftest -I/Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.1 -I/Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/Users/Chintan/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE    -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -I/Users/Chintan/.rvm/usr/include -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib -L. -L/Users/Chintan/.rvm/usr/lib     -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
/Users/Chintan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:317: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/heroku/bin in PATH, mode 040777
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```

Comment: did you install the xcode command line tools?  are they in your path?

Comment: They're definitely installed. How would I check if they're in my path?

Comment: contents of mkmf.log please? (is gcc in your path? you can check by running $ which gcc)

Comment: type `echo $PATH` to show everything that's in your path. If you want to check whether a specific component is in your path, type `which gcc` or `which make` for example. If your terminal doesn't output anything when you do that, it's not in your path. To add something to your path, do this: `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/file/here
export PATH`

Comment: gcc is in my path, any idea where I'd find mkmf.log? @rogerdpack

Comment: possibly /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/debugger-1.6.0/ext/ruby_debug or  /Users/Chintan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/debugger-1.6.0

Comment: @rogerdpack Updated OP with the contents of the log

Comment: so now create a conftest.c file with those contents and try that command line on it :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
gem update debugger-ruby_core_source
```